# Dot Net web form url hide mask

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

i have link which let user login to my portal
//107.10.86.47:1002/login.aspx

how to set it become like this?user cannot view what page/folder he access,the address bar only will display,no matter what page he/she visit
//107.10.86.47:1002/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a frameset. This will display the same url wherever you go.

```
<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame src="startpage.aspx">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dag Bararseen's answer is correct, but masking URLs in an iFrame is bad practice.

As it's a portal, I'm assuming SEO isn't an issue here, but from a usability point of view it's a bit of a nightmare. You're making it hard for users to be able to link to pages directly. It's also really easy to get around, as the user can just look at the source of the iFrame and paste that directly in the browser anyway.

Is there a reason why you want to mask the URLs?